# Где можно расшифровать/декодировать этот текст?

Tags: json_encode

backUsageMsg=\u00a76\u0412\u043e\u0437\u0432\u0440\u0430\u0449\u0430\u0435\u043c\u0441\u044f \u043e\u0431\u0440\u0430\u0442\u043d\u043e...

Comment: @Dmitry151, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в адресной строке браузера напечатать:

```
javascript:backUsageMsg="\u00a76\u0412\u043e\u0437\u0432\u0440\u0430\u0449\u0430\u0435\u043c\u0441\u044f \u043e\u0431\u0440\u0430\u0442\u043d\u043e";alert(backUsageMsg);void(0)
```

(обратите внимание на дополнительные кавычки).

У меня получается такое:

[image]

Comment: Огромная благодарность Вам!У меня получилось расшифровать текст! :)

Answer (score 0):

- Если это нужно сделать вручную - то, например, тут http://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=ru
- если в js - то может подойти unescape(str);

Answer (score 0):

Неплохой декодер для расшифровки много чего: http://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/decoder/